# Удалить элемент массива, и сдвинуть его 1234 1340

Tags: java

Набросал код на свой уровень интеллекта , подскажите как быть дальше

```
public static void delIndex( int[] array,int index) {
   array[index]=0;

for (int i = index; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[index]=array[index+1];

}
```

Comment: Какой элемент удалить? Напишите подробнее задачу

Comment: например массив {12345}  удаляем 1 индекс {13450}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        
        arr = removeValue(arr, 4);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
    
    public static int[] removeValue(int[] array, int index)
    {
        int[] result = new int[array.length]; //создаем массив длиною во входной
        int c = 0; //перменная для смещения значений после удаленного числа
        
        if(index >= array.length) //проверка на то, что индекс меньше длины массива
        {
            new Exception("Индекс больше длины массива!").printStackTrace(); //создание исключения для красивой красной ошибки
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) //цикл в котором происходит вся магия
        {
            if(i != index) //если текущий индекс не равен индексу который нужно удалить
            {
                result[i -c] = array[i]; //записываем в итоговый массив число из начального со смещением '-c'
            }
            else //иначе прибавляем переменную смещения
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        
        return result; //возвращаем конечный результат
    }
}
```

Comment: добавить бы еще комментарии к коду ( разжевать Q_Q)

Comment: добавил комментариев)

Comment: @doodocina и чему Вы только учите других - `new Exception("Индекс больше длины массива!").printStackTrace())`. Где выход из метода?

Comment: ваш код например, хоть и выглядит красиво, но медленнее моего практически в 3 раза =)

Comment: @doodocina я бы поспорил - бенчмарки не Вы, не я не делали

Comment: лично я делал) говорите за себя

Comment: не понимаю только как на 4 индексе ноль получается, если мы удаляем 0 индекс, то цикл понятен, а вот как на 4 индексе ноль получается не понимаю. Вроде понял, он изначально ноль

Comment: изначально размер массива равен размеру входного массива. поэтому все переменные которым мы не присвоили значения по умолчанию будут равны 0

Comment: получается когда есть условие про сдвиг массива нужно работать с копированием массива, а без копирования возможно его сдвинуть?

Comment: конечно, можно сделать и без копирования, но не вижу в этом смысла. код получится намного сложнее и медленнее

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(
            String[] args) {
        int[] array =
                delIndex(
                        new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                        2);
        System.out.println(
                Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static int[] delIndex(
            int[] array,
            int index) {
        System.arraycopy(
                array, index + 1,
                array, index, array.length - index - 1);
        array[array.length - 1] = 0;
        return array;
    }
}
```